# Git rebase not doing rebase

Tags: git, rebase

Sometimes when I type `git rebase`, it is not doing what it is supposed to do.

Case 1. When I type `git rebase origin master`, it checks out master and does nothing.

[image: Image1]

Case 2. I need to type `git rebase master`, twice then it will start to rebase.

[image: Image2]

Comment: In image 1, you are on master already so in essence you're trying to rebase master on master, and yes, then it is already up to date. As for the second image I don't know what happened there because you had unstaged changes, my guess is that you removed those before trying again. It is a good habit to **read the messages**.

Comment: In Image 1, it was from other branch but after type `rebase master` it checkout to master.

The Image 2 might related to git cache or some bug about git.

Comment: The command-line syntax for `git rebase` includes `git rebase <upstream> <branch>`. This particular syntax is what you used as your first command in image 1. That particular syntax directs Git to run `git checkout <branch>` as its first step, and `git rebase <upstream>` as its second, so case 1 moved you from whatever branch you were on before, to `master`. Your second image uses `git rebase <upstream>` so it does not first `git checkout` some other branch.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me why, in your second image, you get an error the first time, and then a successful rebase the second time. Perhaps you have other commands running in other windows that are making changes?